# Set hibernate naming strategy as Spring bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application with Hibernate. I want to provide custom `NamingStrategy` to add prefix to every table managed by hibernate.

I found I can use property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=com.whatever.MyNamingStrategy
```

This works fine except I want to have the prefix dynamic based on properties. My goal would be to have something like:

```
@Component
public class PrefixNamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

    private final String prefix;

    @Autowired
    public PrefixNamingStrategy(@Value("db.table.prefix") String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName) {
        return prefix + super.tableName(tableName);
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work with the property.

I tried to provide custom `SessionFactory`and provide the `NamingStrategy` there but had no luck - the bean was created after hibernate initialized and even doesn't seem to be used:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

    sessionBuilder.setNamingStrategy(...); // !

    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Is there a way how to provide custom `NamingStrategy` as bean?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well knowing this is less than ideal I ended up going through `VendorAdapter`:

1. The naming strategy delegator (note `NamingStrategy` has been deprecated):

   ```
   @Component
   public class PrefixNamingStrategyDelegator extends ImprovedNamingStrategyDelegator {

   @Autowired
   public PrefixNamingStrategyDelegator(final @Value("${application.environment}_") String prefix) {
       super(
               new HbmNamingStrategyDelegate() {
                   @Override
                   public String toPhysicalTableName(String tableName) {
                       return prefix + super.toPhysicalTableName(tableName);
                   }
               },
               new JpaNamingStrategyDelegate() {
                   @Override
                   public String toPhysicalTableName(String tableName) {
                       return prefix + super.toPhysicalTableName(tableName);
                   }
               }
       );
   }

   @Override
   public NamingStrategyDelegate getNamingStrategyDelegate(boolean isHbm) {
       return super.getNamingStrategyDelegate(isHbm);
   }
   }
   ```
2. The `JpaPersistenceProvider` to sneak the `NamingStrategyDelegator` into it:

   ```
   @Component
   /**
    * See {@link org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider}
    *
    * We can't subclass that class but still need to sneak {@link org.hibernate.cfg.naming.NamingStrategyDelegator} into it.
    */
   public class SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProviderWithNamingStrategy extends HibernatePersistenceProvider {

   private final NamingStrategyDelegator namingStrategy;

   @Autowired
   public SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProviderWithNamingStrategy(NamingStrategyDelegator namingStrategy) {
       this.namingStrategy = namingStrategy;
   }

   @Override
   public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(final PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
       return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(info), properties) {
           @Override
           public Configuration buildHibernateConfiguration(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
               Configuration configuration = super.buildHibernateConfiguration(serviceRegistry);
               if (info instanceof SmartPersistenceUnitInfo) {
                   for (String managedPackage : ((SmartPersistenceUnitInfo) info).getManagedPackages()) {
                       configuration.addPackage(managedPackage);
                   }
               }

               configuration.setNamingStrategyDelegator(namingStrategy);

               return configuration;
           }
       }.build();
   }
   }
   ```
3. In my `@Configuration`:

   ```
   @Bean
   public AbstractJpaVendorAdapter customJPAVendorAdapter(HibernatePersistenceProvider jpaPersistenceProvider) {
       return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
           @Override
           public PersistenceProvider getPersistenceProvider() {
               return jpaPersistenceProvider;
           }
       };
   }
   ```

The `PersistenceProvider` itself is raw copy (its package private and can't be sub classed) of `SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider` with added line:

```
configuration.setNamingStrategyDelegator(namingStrategy);
```

Works. But ugly as ... (you know)